# How to test whether a position in an array exists

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to test whether char[i] exists.
For example:

```
char[] c = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
```

Positions 0 - 4 exist but the following results in an error:

```
System.out.println(c[5]);
```

Essentially, how can I return a boolean that is true if c[i] exists and false if not?

Comment: Are you asking in the context of a specific programming language?

Comment: Please check `c.length` first.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
int i = 5;
boolean exists = c.length >= i - 1;
```

Because of `char` can not hold a `null` value, there is no non-existing character in between.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean fun(char[] c, int i){
If(i < c.length)
return true;
else
return false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on mobile currently, so I'm not posting any code, but you could have a method that you pass an array and an index to that uses a try-catch clause to return a Boolean based on whether an exception is thrown or not.

Comment: yea, visiting death-star 2.0? Working with planing faults now? Damit rebells! watch your steps if you walk down your troops while posting SO. ;D

Comment: @PeterRader Damn kids keep breaking my planet destroyers. Can't find decent insurance anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` to catch the `c[i]` exists or not. I hope, you could also reference this [website](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-how-to-handle-array-index-out-of-bounds-exception/).

Comment: Catching exceptions is not a good way to do things when you could simply check `c.length` and compare it to `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
public boolean isElementExist(Object[] arr, int index){
      if(index < 0)
           return false;
      return arr.length - index > 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] c = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
    int input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter an index you want to display"));
    int i =  c.length-1;

    if(input > i ){

        System.out.print("The index: "+input+" does not exist\n there are only "+ i+" in the array \n");       
    }
    else System.out.print("The char at index "+input+" is: "+c[input]+"\n");         
}
```

> Try this out.

Comment: Assuming i is 3, based on the example above `c.length()` is `4` and `i[3]` is `l` is ascii-code `108`, so you compare `108 == 4`! Seriously?

Comment: `108` looks not like "the right track". Can you work your answer out?